# Scipy ODE integration using dopri5 method

Tags: python

while solving coupled differential equation I got following error and I don't get it as I am new in python .

"dopri5: step size becomes too small
  self.messages.get(idid, 'Unexpected idid=%s' % idid))

"
please someone help me with proper explanation about ode integrator .

```js
 # zombie apocalypse modeling
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
from scipy.integrate import ode

G=6.67384*10**(-11)
K=5380.3
v=5/3
r0=1
density0=5*10**(7)
Pressure0=K*density0**(v)
mass0=(4/3)*np.pi*density0*r0**(3)
c=299792458
y_0=[mass0,Pressure0]



def f(r,y):
    mass1=4*np.pi*(y[1]/K)**(1/v)
    Pressure1=G*(  ((y[1]/K)**(1/v)) + (y[1]/(c**2))  )*( (y[0])+(4*np.pi*(r**3)*y[1]/(c**2))  )/( 1-G*y[0]/(r*c**2) )
    #phi1=( G*y[0] + (4*np.pi*G*r**(3)*P/(c**2))   )/( (r*c**2)*( r-2*G*m/(c**2) ) 
    return([mass1,Pressure1])#,phi1)



def my_odeint(f, y0, t):
    '''
    ODE integrator compatible with odeint, that uses ode underneath
    '''
    
    y0 = np.asarray(y0)
    
    backend = "dopri5"
    #backend = "dop853"
    
    solver = ode(f)
    solver.set_integrator(backend)  # nsteps=1
    
    t0 = t[0]
    t_final = t[-1]
    
    solver.set_initial_value(y0, t0)
    
    y_result = [y0]
    
    i = 1
    current_t = t[i]
    z=y0
    while solver.successful() and solver.t < t_final and z[1]>0:
        solver.integrate(current_t, step=1)
        i += 1
        z=solver.y
        if i<len(t) :
            current_t = t[i]
            print(i)
    
        y_result.append(solver.y)
    
    return np.array(y_result)

t_1=np.linspace(10,10**5,10**5)
print(len(t_1))
cal=my_odeint(f,y_0,t_1)
```

Comment: Check th`5/3` and `4/3` do really give the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to solve this, especially since scipy has no implicit methods...

dopri5 or also known as rk45 is a Runge-Kutta method that blends an order-4 and an order-5 method. The order-5 method is used as proxy for the exact value to estimate the error of the order-4 method. If the error does not fall into a predetermined range relative to step-size and problem scale, the step-size is reduced or increased. This allows to steer the integration to have some predetermined global error with close to minimal effort.

In stiff systems it can happen that the step-size reduction never succeeds in driving the error back into admissible territory. There are probably some fail-safes involved so that this bad behavior is found over a noticeable part of the integration interval, invalidating all error estimates.

The solution for the integration of stiff systems is to use implicit methods such as collocation methods. I did not find a hint of them in scipy.

Comment: I hope your answer will help me